# How to split in Perl with blanks and leading zeros

Tags: perl

Sorry for the trivial question but here it is. I have a file to parse. It starts with some blank spaces then the first field then more blank spaces, another field, etc.

For example:

```
000123 KST B4765
```

I split it as follows:

```
my @fields = split /\s+/;
```

It works OK in splitting with one exception: `$fields[0]` is `123` and I would like to retain it as `"000123"` just as it is - a plain string.

Here is the complete part:

```
open UU, "<$file", or die;
while (<UU>) {
  chomp;
  next if /^\#/;
  my @fields = split/\s+/;
  my $pno = 'EQ'."$fields[1]";
  print "$pno\n";
}
```

Comment: `$ perl -le '$_ = "000123 KST B4765"; my @a = split /\s+/; print $a[0]'` output is `000123`

Comment: You should show the other code that affects your field, because `split` has nothing to do with `000123` being converted to `123`.

Comment: The code you have shown us won't strip leading zeroes from fields. If you use the string value `"000123"` in arithmetic it will be treated as decimal `123`, but there is nothing in this code that will do that. Perhaps you need to post your entire program?

Answer (score 3):

No, `000123` will be stored as a string. You may see it as a number if you accidentally convert it into a number, however. E.g.

```
my @fields = split ' ', "000123 KST B4765";
print $fields[0];   # prints 000123
$fields[0] += 0;    # converts string to number
print $fields[0];   # prints 123
```

Note also that using `/\s+/` is similar to using the default `' '` in that it splits on whitespace, except that it will not strip leading whitespace, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: In front of 000123 there are some whitespaces  .I have my $fields=split/\s+/;print $fields[1]; #prints 123  and not 000123.

Comment: Here is the complete part: 1.open UU,"<$file",or die; 2.while (<UU>){ chomp;3.next if /^\#/; 4.my @fields=split/\s+/; 5.my $pno='EQ'."$fields[1]";6.print "$pno\n"; }

Comment: With that code I get the output `EQ000123`. Although of course I removed the weird 1,2,3,4 numbers and the extra comma in the open statement. I assume those were typos and comments.

Comment: Also, when posting code that demonstrates your problem, make sure it is complete, or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/). You can add input with the `__DATA__` internal file handle.